# How to run external task from Eclipse

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I am considering moving to Eclipse, for working on multiple static HTML files, etc.
My current setup lets me hit a single button to run an external task, which runs my build process, purely for that one file. Other files in the same set may have been updated too, but aren't ready to be deployed, so a solution that looks for modified files won't be suitable.

How can I achieve this with Eclipse, or possibly Visual Studio Code?
So far, the only tool I have found is Antrunner4e. which doesn't appear to have been updated for five years.
Similarly, the only way to come close to this in Ant itself appears to be to look for recently modified files, which isn't going to be suitable, but maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: In Eclipse, Ant build files can be directly run as external tool (_Run > External Tools > External Tools Configurations..._). A shortcut for _Runs the last launched external Tool_ can be specified in _Window > Preferences: General > Keys_. Further, [an Ant file can be run as project builder](https://help.eclipse.org/latest/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/gettingStarted/qs-92_project_builders.htm), but that's not what you want (for reasons that are not clear to me), right?

Comment: @howlger  That would only be useful if Ant can be given a reference to the current file, which doesn't seem to be possible?  
Essentially, I may be working on several 'branches' at the same time, so directory-based stuff is going to pick up changes that I don't want it to.

Comment: In the external tool configuration you can specify a property with a value containing a variable like `${selected_resource_loc}` to get the current selected file in the Ant script. There are also variables to prompt for a file or folder when running the Ant script.